# Hidden by the Vegetable Lie

Tags: riddle

Sage of mountain, oracle of sky,

Hidden by the vegetable lie.

Dutch affection in voices gilt

When Windy City's tower was built.

Bane of the hasty, raven's prey,

Powers grown from birth to today.

Yet, I am unchanged in the end.

Do you know my name, dear friend?

---

Hint/alternative/improved scansion version:

> I'm sage of earth, seer of the sky,
>
> Use obscured by carrot lie.
>
> Dutch song my appellation told
>
> During crisis of black gold.
>
> Bane of the hasty, friend of fuzz
>
> AKA sub eyeball cuz.
>
> In the end, I am the same
>
> As from the start. Please guess my name.

Comment: Aw, dang, after spending some significant time on this, I just thought of an idea for a couple more  lines.  Maybe I will add something if this takes more than 5-10 minutes to solve.

Comment: Enlighten us, please.

Comment: @IvanBarreto Done.  I will also post, as a hint,  what I think is an easier version of the whole thing in a couple of days.

Comment: "Hidden by the vegetable lie" is like a line from a parody of a Dio song.

Comment: "Holland" (Dutch) is an album by The Beach Boys (golden voices), released in 1973 (when the Willis Tower was built in Chicago).

Comment: @Alconja Well, if we ignore the rest of the riddle, that works about as well as what I hope someone might get from those two lines.  Maybe the new version helps.

Comment: @question_asker I did not know that. The (easier?  better?  possibly worse or more confusing and I just don't know it yet?) new version I've been teasing is posted now.  I'd love criticism or comparison on either version, too.

Comment: Oh I was just being silly

Comment: Why not just replace the old version with the improvement?

Comment: @dennisdeems Is it that much better than the original?  It is hard for me to tell.  Some of the "improvement" lines are actually from my first or second draft.  I do think that it is at least easier.

Comment: I think it's better, yes.  The original may make better poetry, but the new version makes a better riddle.

Answer (score 8):

My answer is

> **RADAR**

because:

I'm sage of earth, seer of the sky,

> Radar looks into the earth and into the sky

Use obscured by carrot lie.

> British used radar during ww2, but allegedly convinced the Germans their spotting skills were due to improved eye sight thanks to eating carrots (credit to @Alconja)

Dutch song my appellation told
During crisis of black gold.

> The Netherlands sung "I See a Star" at the Eurovision Song Contest in 1974 (during the oil crisis).

Bane of the hasty, friend of fuzz

> Police uses radar to catch speeders.

AKA sub eyeball cuz.

> Sub eyeball, is referring to the wavelength being below the visible spectrum. (credit to @Alconja)

In the end, I am the same
As from the start.

> Refers to radar being a palindrome

Comment: Welcome to [puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com)!  That's not what I am looking for, but some of your thinking *could* be in the right direction, but it is hard to say for sure.  Some, however, is not.  It should be possible to find meaning in every line (aside from the last one).  Could you explain how you got your fitting date?  Also, and some may disagree with me, but I like it when people use the >! to spoilertag the key parts of their answers.

Comment: I didn't know how to write a spoiler. Thanks. Will think some more :)

Comment: The Willis tower in Chicago was built in 1973.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks :) But, apparently, I was wrong anyway :)

Comment: The new version is posted now.

Comment: Yep agreed on your edit. Well done. Some more points: the British used radar during ww2, but allegedly convinced the Germans their spotting skills were due to improved eye sight thanks to eating carrots. Sub eyeball, is referring to the wavelength being below the visible spectrum.

Comment: I edited to have the format a bit more to how these types of questions are usually answered. Alconja has some good insight into the missing hints you had, you should probably edit those in (and give credit)

Comment: "Radar Love" by Dutch band Golden Earring came out in 73

Comment: This actually makes much more sense :)

Comment: That's it!  You can see your first guess was not as far off as you might have thought.  There are some more hints in there, though, or cases where I intended the clue to point to something that I *think* is more direct than what you posted.  One of those is still in the comments, courtesy of @question_asker.

Comment: @Alconja Good work.  The latter part isn't what I intended, though it seems to fit anyway.  "Cuz" was intended to be short for cousin and part of the clue rather than an interjection inserted simply for the sake of rhyming.